# Read Notifications of other apps from windows 10 action center

Tags: c#, windows-10

Is it possible to read notifications programmatically from windows 10 action center of other apps like notifications from the default mail application.

I googled a lot, I found answers to show toast notification and read notification of current app but how would one read notifications of another apps. There is a app in windows store which does the same, so it seems possible.

Can anyone steer me in right direction. Any language will do.

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For UWP application there is a class 'UserNotificationListener'